# SQLite Parsing TEXT column with date info

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'am using SQLite DB and I have "**Date**" column that is VARCHAR

I need to extract data between 2 dates...

this is what I tried....

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Date BETWEEN '14/03/2017 17:00:10' AND '16/03/2018 17:00:12'
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S', Date) BETWEEN  strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S','15/07/2016 20:00:09') AND  strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S','16/07/2017 21:00:09')
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S', Date) BETWEEN  '2017/07/15 20:00:09' AND  '2017/07/17 21:00:09'
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a date/time column, then just do:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.Date >= '2017-03-14 17:00:10' AND
      t1.Date < '2018-03-16 17:00:12';
```

Use ISO/ANSI standard date formats for constants!

I strongly discourage you from using `between` with date/time values.  [Here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) is a blog post on the subject, which although for SQL Server applies to all databases.

Comment: I am using range: '15/07/2017' to '16/07/2017' and for some reason it is returning data from 15/08/2017 as well.

Comment: @AndrzejKoloszewski . . . I guess you didn't get the hint.  Use ISO/ANSI standard formats for date constants:  YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: I know that date format, unfortunately it is legacy DB and I can not do this easily. :( the whole point is to use it with current date format.

Comment: @AndrzejKoloszewski when comparing dates you should use the ANSI standard format for the date constants. If you have a legacy DB then convert the column value(s) to a date/time format before trying to compare.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use SQLite's `strftime` because it's *formatting* function, it can not parse input string.

Basically you have two options:

1. try to parse string using builtin functions
2. create user defined function

If you can rely on the fixed positions, you can easily parse your string and format it back to comply with one of supported [SQLite DateTime formats](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). In your case it might look like this:

```
SELECT [Date] FROM Table1 WHERE 
DATETIME(printf('%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d', 
    substr([Date], 7, 4), substr([Date], 4, 2), substr([Date], 1, 2), 
    substr([Date], 12, 2), substr([Date], 15, 2), substr([Date], 18, 2))) 
BETWEEN '2017-07-15 20:00:05' AND '2017-07-17 21:00:09'
```

Please note you have to change also syntax of `BETWEEN` to match one of supported `DATETIME` formats.